# How to open New List Item Form in modal dialog in a SharePoint 2010 page from different site collection

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, modal-dialog, sharepoint-designer

I need to open a new list item form on hyperlink, or button click, in a Sharepoint 2010 page. The page and the list are in different site collections. I must do this from the Sharepoint Designer, or directly editing the page in a browser, Visual studio project is not possible/allowed...

Can this be done, and how?

Answer (score 3):

P.S. Most safe way to address New form is to use ListForm.aspx page, as follows:

```
 /_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=8&ListId={PUT-LIST-GUID-HERE}
```

(PageType value goes from [PAGETYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.pagetype.aspx) enumeration)

i think you should be work when use `PAGE_NEWFORMDIALOG : New form for a file dialog box.Value=9` as describe on msdn. if New form is not open on model pop up than

Try this :

#### HyperLink

```
 <a href='javascript:;' onclick='Opendialog()'>New Item</a>
```

#### Opendialog is Javascript Function

```
   function Opendialog() {
       var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
       options.resizable = 1;
       options.scroll = 1;
       options.url = SiteURLWhichExistList + "/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=8&ListId={PUT-LIST-GUID-HERE}";
       options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback);
       SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
   }
```

Note : `SiteURLWhichExistList`  pass your site collection url in where your list exist.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I've done something very similar to this, but I'm still having one more problem. As a form (the one I'm showing in a popup) is on another site collection, after I submit data, it does not close automatically. Instead I'm getting javascript error "Access is denied". Do you have any idea how to get around this?

Comment: In most cases, you can use _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl for that "SiteURLWhichExistList" replace-me-with-your-value var in your example. Btw, your example worked fabulous for me, thanks. I +1'd it.